# VBA Sumproduct returns #value! on cell - How do I fix my code to avoid this error?

Tags: excel, vba, sumproduct

I have a workbook that had links to about 80 other workbooks. It was really slow to load up. I decided to stop using links to speed it up. This meant finding a way to use VBA sumproduct to carry out some of the calculations. I have a headache now since I am getting #Value! error from my VBA code.

```
 option explicit

Sub VBA_Sumproduct

Dim rng_1 as range

Dim op_cell as range

Dim Model as String

Dim formula as string

Dim wb as workbook

dim wb2 as workbook

set wb2 = workbooks("wb2.xlsm")

'workbooks.open("Filepath")

set wb = workbooks("wb1.xlsm")

set rng_1=wb.sheets("A1").range("E2:E500")

set op_cell = wb2.sheets("T1").range("E20")

model = "Complete"

Formula = "sumproduct((rng_1="" & model & "")"

op_cell = application.evaluate(Formula)

wb.save

wb.close

end sub
```

Comment: You can't use `rng_1` like that inside a formula... you need its address. And make sure you evaluate it using the correct sheet as context - `Application.Evaluate` uses the active sheet.

Comment: `Formula = "=sumproduct(--(" & rng_1.Address & "=" & model & "))"`

Comment: Thanks guys. @Scott Craner - I tried using your code I'm now getting #name? Error in the op_cell.

Comment: @big ben. Thanks. I've never used Sumproduct in VBA before. How would you search a column in another workbook and count the number of times a word is in the column. Then return a value in workbook1 in specified cell? I have tried every variation of code.

Comment: COUNTIF probably - you can use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`, and wildcards `*`.

Comment: `Formula = "=sumproduct(--(" & rng_1.Address & "=""" & model & """))"`

Comment: @big ben thank you. Used application.worksheetfunction.countifs and it worked a treat :)